# Convert a List<SpannableString> to a single SpannableString

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a `TextView` which receives a `SpannableString` to it's `TextFormatted` property. The way I want to build this `SpannableString` is like a bullet list, in which if some item meets some condition it's color is changed, otherwise it remains the default text color; I then add every `SpannableString` to a list and at the end I merge them all into a single `SpannableString` to be returned to the `TextView`. The problem is that I can't find a way to do it.

I've already tried adding each `SpannableString`, but the `+` operator doesn't work with them. I've tried using `TextUtils.Concat()`, but they don't seem to work the way they do in Java - in Java they'd accept both `string` and `StringFormatted`, but in Xamarin.Android they only accept `string`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I'm so sorry for no answering your answer. I actually found a way to do it, I'll answer my own question with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Convert a List to a single SpannableString

you could convert the list to **SpannableStringBuilder**:

```
List<SpannableString> spannableStringList = new List<SpannableString>();            
CustomTypefaceSpan customTypefaceSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(typeface);
var spannableString1 = new SpannableString("Hello");
spannableString1.SetSpan(customTypefaceSpan, 0, spannableString1.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
spannableString1.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Green), 0, spannableString1.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
var spannableString2 = new SpannableString("Leo");
spannableString2.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red),0, spannableString2.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
spannableStringList.Add(spannableString1);
spannableStringList.Add(spannableString2);
var ssBuilder= new SpannableStringBuilder();
foreach (var item in spannableStringList)
  {
     ssBuilder.Append(item);
  }
textView.SetText(ssBuilder, BufferType.Spannable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, the same way Xamarin.Android have a `TextView.TextFormatted` property to set a `TextView`'s text to a formatted (`Spannable`) text, it also have a `TextUtils.ConcatFormatted`, which is used to concat `Spannable` objects. With that, I can have:

```
var spans = new List<SpannableString>();
var someSpan = new SpannableString("Foo");
// Style someSpan as needed
spans.Add(someSpan);
var result = new SpannableString(TextUtils.ConcatFormatted(spans.ToArray()));
```